# How to find textarea inside a page with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a Web Form created dynamically.
This Web Form contains controls such as TextBoxes, textareas, RadioButton, CheckBoxes, ListBoxes.

I am able to retrieve all control types data except **textraeas**
Can you help to get `textraea`
The code I am using is the following:

```
Sub get_controls(pagecontrol As Control, ide As String)


        Dim listcontrol As New Generic.List(Of Control)()
        Dim id, val, typecontrol, groupradio As String
        id = ""
        val = ""
        groupradio = ""

        If pagecontrol.ID = "form1" Then
            listcontrol.AddRange(FlattenHierachy_Master(pagecontrol))
        Else
            listcontrol.AddRange(FlattenHierachy(pagecontrol))
        End If

        For Each control As Control In listcontrol

            typecontrol = ""
            If (TypeOf control Is CheckBox) Then
                Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(control, CheckBox)
                id = cb.ID
                val = cb.Checked
                typecontrol = "CheckBox"
            End If

            If (TypeOf control Is TextBox) Then
                Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(control, TextBox)
                id = txt.ID
                val = txt.Text
                typecontrol = "TextBox"
            End If

            If (TypeOf control Is RadioButton) Then
                Dim rdb As RadioButton = DirectCast(control, RadioButton)
                id = rdb.ID
                val = rdb.Checked
                typecontrol = "RadioButton"
                groupradio = rdb.GroupName
            End If


            If (TypeOf control Is DropDownList) Then
                Dim DL As DropDownList = DirectCast(control, DropDownList)
                id = DL.ID
                val = DL.SelectedValue
                typecontrol = "DropDownList"
                groupradio = ""
            End If

            If typecontrol <> "" And id <> "" And val <> "" Then clenquete.save(ide, id, typecontrol, val, "", groupradio, 0)

        Next


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<textarea>` is rendered when an `<asp:TextBox>` has the attribute `TextMode="MultiLine"`: [TextBox.TextMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode).

So `If (TypeOf control Is TextBox) Then` you need to check that property to distinguish them. It can have one of [several values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode), but it's `TextBoxMode.MultiLine` that you need to check for.